# Why Maxwell thought that aether was needed?

Tags: electromagnetism, history, aether

The present knowledge of electromagnetism says that a time-varying electric field generates a time-varying magnetic field and vice versa; this would result in an electromagnetic wave. Maxwell was one the greats who summed up all the seemingly disparate experimental observations into a mathematical language and ended up unifying electric and magnetic fields and predicting the existence of electromagnetic waves.

Aether played an important role in the mathematical derivation and Maxwell's model of electromagnetism where aether was taken to be a medium for the propagation of the electromagnetic wave. Maxwell also tried to come up with a working physical model(s) of aether. Didn't Maxwell see that both electric and magnetic fields can give rise to each other and propagate outward without the need of any separate medium? Why did he need aether at all? Is it possible that he didn't properly realize or visualize that electric and magnetic fields generate each other?

I think that he visualized both fields as some kind of mysterious entities or disturbances in the aether, where one disturbance gives rise to another disturbance in aether and so on. Later when aether was ruled out, those mysterious fluctuating disturbances were considered to be fluctuations and medium in one, i.e. fields. Do I make any sense?

Could you please guide me with it? Thank you!

Comment: Maxwell didn't propose the idea of aether

Comment: Thank you. I understand that Maxwell didn't propose the idea of aether. It was already there. But when Maxwell did the math, didn't he realize that he could do without the aether? I understand that  looking at it in hindsight makes it easier to think  aether was not needed. With sound waves, it was different and more obvious.

Comment: "a time varying electric field generates a time varying magnetic field and vice versa" This is not correct.

Comment: @my2cts Could you please let me know how I have it wrong?

Comment: You may enjoy reading [the article on the aether that Maxwell wrote](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica,_Ninth_Edition/Ether_(2.)) for the Encyclopedia Brittanica.

Comment: At that time every other wave was found to travel through a medium so why not assume that em waves were no different?

Comment: @pg1995 The wave is really a vector potential wave. Since $E = \partial A / \partial t$ and $B = \nabla  \times A$ , both quantities are identically the same and do not generate each other.

Comment: @my2cts **"a time varying electric field generates a time varying magnetic field and vice versa" This is not correct. – my2cts"** . What I said might be somewhat informal or perhaps not very correct, but it's still not wrong. Please have a look here. *"A changing electric field will generate a changing magnetic field all on its own. This would result in a changing electric field, which would result in a a changing magnetic field, and so on — the whole thing flying away out into empty space at the speed of light. - https://physics.info/em-waves/"* . Cont'd

Comment: "Focus on these two facts:
an oscillating electric field generates an oscillating magnetic field
an oscillating magnetic field generates an oscillating electric field
Those two points are key to understanding electromagnetic waves. - http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/PY106/EMWaves.html" . So, in short, you could find many places which say the same thing which suggests that what I said should be acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: @PG1995 In physics, wrong statements are not acceptable no matter how frequent.

Comment: @my2cts Okay. I might be wrong because I'm not well qualified to claim that it is correct. But there are many textbooks, not internet sources, I have come across where the same thing is said. I couldn't provide references to all those books for obvious reasons. "The correct form of Ampère's law (duc to Maxwell) says that a changing clectric flux produces a magnetic field. Since a changing electric flux can be caused by a changing E, we can also say that a changing electric field produces a magetic field. **Cont'd**"

Comment: "There is thus a sort of "circularity" as illustrated in Figu re 23.1: an electric field can (if it is changing) produce a magnetic field, and a magnetic field can (if it is changing) produce an clectric field. Can this "loop" or oscillation involving E and B continue, with the new clectric field producing a new magnetic field, producing a new electric field, and so on? The answer is yes; self-sustaining oscillations involving electric and magnetic fields are indeed possible. **Cont'd**"

Comment: " In fact, such oscillations are an electromagnetic wave. Electromagnetic waves are also referred to as electromagnetic radiation. - College Physics: Reasoning and Relationships, Nicholas Giordano, Page #762"

Comment: @PG1995 Above I stated that the two quantities are identically the same, not generating one another. Use your own judgement.

Answer (score 2):

During those days, the idea of Transverse waves was not available/widely accepted. So Light was thought to be a longitudinal wave(just like sound). But longitudinal waves need an elastic medium for their propagation. Hence the idea of aether was developed. A highly elastic low density medium.

Comment: Maxwell didn't need the idea of Aether at all. He showed that light is an electromagnetic wave which doesn't require any such medium

Comment: No he did not show that. Maxwell's equation s do not rule out an aether. On the contrary, they strongly suggest one since they are formulated with material media in mind.

Comment: @Vilvanesh I'm sorry but you are mistaken. Maxwell tried his hard to prove the medium. On a side note, I'm surprised that you didn't see the details of my question carefully.

Comment: I think that this question should have been asked in history of science forum. Could someone please move it there? Thanks.

Comment: Physicists of that era were certainly familiar with transverse waves! But they knew that gases can't act as a medium for transverse waves. Sound in air is longitudinal, but in solids there are also transverse waves, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound#Longitudinal_and_transverse_waves

Comment: @PG1995 I'd suggest that you post the question there yourself. If you mean [hsm.se], be advised that it's not a good idea to cross-post the exact same question to multiple SE sites, so you should adjust how you frame the question to make it best suited to that site if you post it there.

Comment: @David Z I wasn't going to cross-post. I was rather requesting a moderator to move it there.

Comment: @PG1995 We don't generally do that unless the question is off topic here.

Comment: @David Z I assume that you're one of the moderators. If you don't consider to be off topic and find it in the right forum, then I'm good with it. I had thought that I was better asking it history of science forum because it has more to do with the history. Thanks

Comment: @PG1995 Sounds good. I'm honestly not sure about the question; I can see arguments either way (on topic or off topic), but nobody else who has seen it seems to think it's off topic, so I'm inclined to leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what Maxwell was thinking, but:

Maxwell's equations predict an exact value for the speed of light.  But to a classical (pre-relativity) physicist, the speed of light must be different for different observers.  So it is natural to ask this:  "For what observer are Maxwell's equations correct?".  The natural guess is:  An observer who is standing still.   The natural follow-up question is:  "Standing still relative to what?".  Whatever that "what" is, we might as well call it the aether.

Answer (score 0):

Maxwell wrote in the Encyclopedia Britannica: “We know that the aether transmits transverse vibrations to very great distances without sensible loss of energy by dissipation.” [https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Encyclopædia_Britannica,_Ninth_Edition/Ether_(2.)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica,_Ninth_Edition/Ether_(2.))

So, Maxwell believed light was transverse waves vibrating the aether. Maxwell created his equations based upon mechanisms in a medium that had kinetic energy i.e. momentum and elasticity i.e. displacement. From this he postulated wave vibrations at the speed of light. See book Faraday, Maxwell and the Electromagnetic Field. Maxwell believed that the Electromagnetic Field was the Aether. See his article in the link. His final theory took away the mechanical model around magnets and currents but left the equations because he didn’t know what was actually moving in the space around a magnet or electrical current, but he believed something was actually moving outside of them.

Remember that before Einstein the entire scientific community believed that an aether carried light.